# Responsive Menu Issues

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Ok I have no where near enough knowledge on JS to even know what this could possibly be.

My Navigation menu has stopped working in mobile.

If you resize the browser to mobile then back to desktop then back to mobile the menu shows the menu icon 3 times, if you repeat this it keeps duplicating, but it open and doesnt close after the first time..

You can see it live here qubecatering.com

I have no idea what code this could be..

Any help would be great! Im using the flexymenu plugin, and use this on many sites and never have issues.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="flexy-menu"><ul id="menu-primary" class="flexy-menu"><li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-20"><a href="http://qubecatering.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://qubecatering.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://qubecatering.com/case-studies/">Case Studies</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://qubecatering.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://qubecatering.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

But here is my css:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.nav-inner {
    width:100%;
    max-width:960px;
    height:60px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.nav-logo   {
    height:60px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

/*******************************************************************************
                            Default configuration
*******************************************************************************/

.flexy-menu {
    width: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    display:inline-block;
}

.flexy-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
.flexy-menu > li > a {
    padding:23px 15px 5px 15px; 
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;   
    -moz-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;    
    transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;   

    font-family: 'latoregular';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#32455c;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.flexy-menu > li > a:hover, .flexy-menu > li > a:focus, .flexy-menu > li > a:active {
    background-color:#835db1;
    color:#ffffff;
}


/*-----------------------------
    Drop down configuration
-----------------------------*/
.flexy-menu ul, 
.flexy-menu ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0;  
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 200px;

}
.flexy-menu ul {
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
.flexy-menu ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.flexy-menu ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    border: none;
    font-size:12px;
}
.flexy-menu ul li a {
    padding:15px 20px;
    width:100%;
    color:#dedede;
    font-size:13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;   
    -moz-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;    
    transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(61, 71, 82, 0.8); 
}

.flexy-menu ul li a:hover {

}

/*-----------------------------
    Drop down indicators
-----------------------------*/
.flexy-menu > li .indicator{
    position: absolute;
    color: #7995a7;
    top: 39px;
    right: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.flexy-menu ul > li .indicator{
    top: 10px;
    right: 8px;
}

/*------------------
    Preset sizes
------------------*/
.thin > li > a{
    padding: 10px 22px;
}
.thin ul{
    top: 40px;
}
.thin > li .indicator{
    top: 10px;
}

.thick > li > a{
    padding: 40px 22px;
}
.thick ul{
    top: 100px;
}
.thick > li .indicator{
    top: 40px;
}

/*------------------------------------
    Collapsible menu configuration
------------------------------------*/
.flexy-menu > li.showhide{
    display: none;
    width: 30%;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flexy-menu > li.showhide span.icon{
    margin: 23px 30px;
    float: right;
}
.flexy-menu > li.showhide .icon em{
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #aad730;
}

/*****************************************************************************
                            Responsive design
*****************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .flexy-menu {
        width: 50%;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .flexy-menu li{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    .flexy-menu > li > a{
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }

    .flexy-menu li:hover > a,
    .flexy-menu li.active a {
        border-bottom:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

    .flexy-menu a{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    }
    .flexy-menu ul {
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
    } 
    .flexy-menu ul,
    .flexy-menu ul li ul{
        position: static;
    }
    .flexy-menu ul li ul,
    .flexy-menu ul li {
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .flexy-menu ul li a,
    .flexy-menu.vertical ul li a    {
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
    .flexy-menu ul > li > a{
        padding-left: 40px !important;
    }
    .flexy-menu > li .indicator{
        top: 15px;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    .flexy-menu ul > li .indicator{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$.fn.flexymenu = function(options){
    var settings = {
        speed               : 300,                  // dropdown speed (ms)
        type                : "horizontal",         // menu type arrangement
        align               : "right",              // menu alignment (horizontal type)
        indicator           : false                 // indicator that indicates a submenu
    }
    $.extend( settings, options );

    var bigScreen = false;

    if(settings.type == "vertical"){
        $(".flexy-menu").addClass("vertical");
        if(settings.align == "right"){
            $(".flexy-menu").addClass("right");
        }
    }

    if(settings.indicator == true){
        var num = 0;
        $(".flexy-menu").find("li").each(function(){
            if($(this).children("ul").length > 0){
                $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>+</span>");
            }
        });
    }

    $(".flexy-menu").prepend("<li class='showhide'><span class='icon'><em></em><em></em><em></em></span></li>");

    screenSize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        screenSize();
    });

    function screenSize(){
        $(".flexy-menu").find("li").unbind();
        $(".flexy-menu").find("ul").hide(0);
        if(window.innerWidth <= 768){
            showCollapse();
            bindClick();
            if(bigScreen == true){
                rightAlignMenu();
                bigScreen = false;
            }
        }
        else{
            hideCollapse();
            bindHover();
            if(settings.type == "horizontal" && settings.align == "right" && bigScreen == false){
                rightAlignMenu();
                bigScreen = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function bindHover(){
        $(".flexy-menu li").bind("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn(settings.speed);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function(){
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut(settings.speed);
        });
    }

    function bindClick(){
        $(".flexy-menu > li").bind("click", function(){
            if($(this).children("ul").css("display") == "none"){
                $(this).find("ul").slideDown(settings.interval);
            }
            else{
                $(this).children("ul").slideUp(settings.interval);
            }
        });
    }

    function showCollapse(){
        $(".flexy-menu > li:not(.showhide)").hide(0);
        $(".flexy-menu > li.showhide").show(0);
        $(".flexy-menu > li.showhide").bind("click", function(){
            if($(".flexy-menu > li").is(":hidden")){
                $(".flexy-menu > li").slideDown(300);
            }
            else{
                $(".flexy-menu > li:not(.showhide)").slideUp(300);
                $(".flexy-menu > li.showhide").show(0);
            }
        });
    }

    function hideCollapse(){
        $(".flexy-menu > li").show(0);
        $(".flexy-menu > li.showhide").hide(0);
    }   

    function rightAlignMenu() {
        $(".flexy-menu > li").addClass("right");
        var menuWidth = $(".flexy-menu").width();
        var menuItems = $(".flexy-menu").children("li");
        $(".flexy-menu").children("li:not(.showhide)").detach();
        for(var i = menuItems.length; i >= 1; i--){
            $(".flexy-menu").append(menuItems[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your html?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the need for a whole plugin for such a simple task. probably just css and a little bit of js for togglin class would do the trick.. I will make a fiddle for you

Comment: @DanielOrtiz i have updated the html for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have there is because your appending things into the ".flexy-menu"class, but if you check your html, I see that you added this class in two places, that's the way it's duplicationg

```
<div class="flexy-menu">
    <li class="showhide right" style="display: none;"><span class="icon"><em></em><em></em><em></em></span>
    </li>
    <ul id="menu-primary" class="flexy-menu" style="">
```

try removing it from the  element

Edit

Great! anyway I strongly recommend you to use another approach next time. You can just use javascript to toggle a class on the navigation bar and using css to show and hide the menu. It's as simple as that

```
(function () {
    var navBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar'),
        toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');


    toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        navBar.classList.toggle('active');
    });
})();
```

Comment: I have put the old static html menu in place and its working fine.. Doesnt explain why its not like that on my other sites. Thank you for helping me out :)